# Print only even/odd pages of pdf in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, pdf, printing

I am forced to work on a Windows 8 machine that I have no administrative rights for. It seems that the built-in pdf viewer does not support to print only odd or even pages. Which pdf viewer (or other software) should I suggest the admin to install on my machine so that I have this feature available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take this one: http://www.adobe.com/products/reader.html

> Open Odd numbered pdf file in
>   Adobe reader ( Here I am taking a pdf file with 81 pages, 81 is an Odd
>   numbere ). Press Ctrl+P to print the document. Select Subeset: Select
>   Odd pages only Under the print rage Settings. Now  print all the odd
>   numbered pages, ie: 1,3,5,7,9,11,.....81.

Answer (score 2):

I press ctrl+p to bring up the windows print dialog.  I then click "preferences" to bring up the "printing preferences" menu.  I then click "advanced."

In the Advanced Options menu expand the Document Options folder and then expand the Printer Features folder.  Under Printer Features you will see "Pages to print - print all pages." If you click on "print all pages" it will present a drop down menu giving you the option to print all pages, **print odd pages only** or **print even pages only**.

I hope that helps.

Also if you are using Chrome press ctrl+shift+p to bypass the chrome print dialog and go strait to the windows8 print dialog.

PS please be sure to tell your I.T. department how much windows 8 is slowing down your productivity and wasting company money.  I hate Windows 8.

Comment: I have not tried Windows 10 yet.  I really want directx12 on my windows 7 machine. :(